# How can I disable NeoGrub Bootloader on Console?

Tags: dual-boot, boot-repair, easybcd

I want to dualboot window 8 Pro and ubuntu.It can't boot ubuntu in first time,then i use easyBCD  to change window boot Manager to boot ubuntu.I add Entries and Install NeoGrub.when I restart on Windows Boot Manager screen it has only "NeroGrub Bootloader" that I can choose.window 8 is disappeared ,then I use ubuntu "trying ubuntu mode" and use Boot-repair to repair grub.it 's work and return this : http://paste.ubuntu.com/6655010/ ,Now I can boot to my ubuntu,but window can't.on grub boot list I have

- Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-23-generic
- Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-23-generic(recover mode)
- Windows UEFI bkpbootmgfw.efi
- Window Boot UEFI loader
- efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
- Window 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda4)

when I choose "Windows UEFI bkpbootmgfw.efi" or "Window Boot UEFI loader",it's go to Window Boot Manager screen and has only one choice "NeoGrub Bootloader".When i choose It's show error like

> Window failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be cause. To fix the problem:
>      .
>      .  more details
>      .
>     file: \NST\NeoGrub.mbr
>     status: 0xc000000f
>     Info: The application or operating system couldn't be loaded ...

Help me please! I stuck with this problem for a week. 
 Thankyou very much for all answer,Sorry for my weak skill grammar.
 Tell me if you want more information or don't understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *repair* your windows bootloader and then make *grub2* as default bootloader.To do that follow the below steps,

- Boot *windows installation disk* then select the "*windows repair*" or "*repair your computer*" option before you go into the installation process.
- After selecting windows repair option,it will take you to the next screen.In that screen select the "command prompt" option
- Then run the below commands,on it.

  ```
  bootrec /fixmbr
  bootrec /fixboot
  bootrec /rebuildbcd
  ```
- This will repair your windows bootloader.
- Atlast ran [*boot-repair-disk*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and click on the *recommended repair* option.Now it works.

Comment: thanks a lots for your answer. I follow your suggest,it's success except,when i type "bootrec /rebuildbcd" and it's show "[1] C:\Windows" was found,and I type 'Y' for submit it.it's return "The request system device cannot be found".and when I restart it's not work.

Comment: after that try boot-repair.

Comment: ok,I tried on ubuntu boot form Grub.it's not work.it's has same problem.it's boot to Window Boot manager and has only one NeoGrub,and when i choose Window 8 (loader) it's show "error" unknown command 'drivemap' " and "invalid EFI file path.".
result form boot-repair : http://paste.ubuntu.com/6655941